Mute speakers temporarily
I've setup a tool to grab the audio on my phone and play it on my computer.
But I don't want it play the audio while I'm rerouting the audio.
Currently I've set the volume to one, But it's still noticeable.
And it means I can't just use the volume buttons to adjust the volume, But I have to do it through the audio widget on my dock.

I am flagging it as a programming question
